# How to use the Python driver for Cassandra to connect to the cluster with keystore and truststore files?

Tags: python, cassandra

I can use keystore and trustore files with the password string to connect to Datastax Dev Center. However, I looked around the internet but there's no documentation about how to use these files with the Python driver for Cassandra. Everything is about certificate and keystore files only.

I get the error "ssl:3517" when connecting to the host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python driver doesn't work with keystore/trustore yet (they are Java-specific). You need to export your certificate and key from these files into PEM format, and connect as described in [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.16/security/#ssl):

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from ssl import PROTOCOL_TLSv1, CERT_REQUIRED

ssl_opts = {
    'ca_certs': '/path/to/my/ca.certs',
    'ssl_version': PROTOCOL_TLSv1,
    'cert_reqs': CERT_REQUIRED  # Certificates are required and validated
}
cluster = Cluster(ssl_options=ssl_opts)
```

if cluster has client's certificate check enabled, then you need to specify `keyfile` and `certfile` parameters in the `ssl_opts` dictionary, passing the path to key and certificate files. See python's documentation for all [available options](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html#ssl.wrap_socket).

You can extract data from keystore and convert into supported PEM format with something like this:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore myapp.jks -destkeystore myapp.p12 \
  -srcalias myapp-dev -srcstoretype jks -deststoretype pkcs12
openssl pkcs12 -in myapp.p12 -out myapp.pem
```